# It says "you have entered too many arguments for this function" while using Nested IF in MS-Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using the below excel formula, but getting an error that "you have entered too many arguments for this function". Is there any other way I can make this function work please?

```
IF(N11="MS",IF(M11<3.4,"",IF(AND(3.4<=M11,M11<=5.4),0.5716*M11+2.498,0.8126*M11+1.1723)),IF(N11="mb",IF(AND(3.9<=M11,M11<=6.8),1.0319*M11+0.0223,"")),IF(N11="ML",IF(AND(3.3<=M11,M11<=6.6),0.8095*M11+1.3003,"")))
```

Comment: Try using `IFS` instead. It will simplify the parentheses.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say you had entered too many arguments. Check your commas and brackets.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can have upto 7 nest IF statements, if your version of Excel supports (Excel 365 or 2019) it you can use IFS instead of IF for more criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As `Naz` says, you can nest too far. But the problem here is different. Your formula can have some spaces and such added to it to look like this:

```
=IF(N11="MS",
 IF(M11<3.4,  "",  IF(  AND(3.4<=M11,M11<=5.4),  0.5716*M11+2.498,  0.8126*M11+1.1723)),

 IF(N11="mb",
 IF(  AND(3.9<=M11,M11<=6.8),  1.0319*M11+0.0223,  "")),

 IF(N11="ML",
 IF(  AND(3.3<=M11,M11<=6.6),  0.8095*M11+1.3003,  ""))
 )
```

The first line says "if this particular thing is true, then line two, otherwise go to line three. On line 2, you have another `IF()` and it is COMPLETE:  it says if this thing is true, then this thing, otherwise that thing. But if you match up the parentheses, you see it is completely separated from everything else... it is a whole thing. But that's OK because the first line has to offer up something for TRUE and something for FALSE. This whole thing is what happens for TRUE. A nice, simple world, just one little set of stuff can happen if the first line is true and this is all of it. You could have several more `IF()`'s getting to that point, but cool, you don't, it's easy.

And then the false pathway begins. This one is not as easy. It start off like the first line saying if this is true, then... line four. A nice, parallel construction, must be all good, eh? So like the first true in line two, it presents three things:  asks if something is true or false, has a result for it being true, and one for it being false. Still, no problem... but the very next character ruins it all. Line 4, that last `)` before the ending comma:  it is extra. the `IF()` you are looking at for the true branch from line three's test ends with the `)` BEFORE IT.

So this one matches back to an earlier one, and the last one that is unmatched, going back is the one right before `N11="mb"` and that means this `)` ends your `IF()` chain. You have the first test in line one. You have the true branch in line two. And now you have a complete, ended false branch right here in lines three and four. So the `IF()` has all three of its pieces:  test, true result, false result.

EVERYTHING coming after this is extra. All of lines five and six are extra. All that extra stuff starts here and ends right before the very last `)` in the formula. It is a FOURTH part to a function that can only deal with THREE parts.

UNhelpfully, Excel puts the cursor at the very end of the failure causing material instead of right at its beginning. Since that happens to be almost the very end of everything, you get the feeling the failure must involve just about everything. But no, it does not.

By the way, the nesting limit is for a CHAIN, going and going and going. So, to make it very clear, it is like this:

```
=IF(IF(IF(IF(IF(IF(IF(IF(...
```

that causes the problem. It is NOT NOT NOT cause just by having three-four-five branches, then back up to "top" level and having three-four-five branches, then back up to "top" level and... but wait, you already have more than seven nestings if you add the first four, say, and that second five... NO. The have to nest within each other, not alongside each other. It's how long one chain is, not how many nested levels there are altogether. Think of those Russian dolls, not the doll aisle at Walmart.

So, when you take out that `)`, your error goes away.

Still, you COULD use other approaches. The `IFS()` suggestion is hugely good both because it's easy to do:  set up in an empty place in the spreadsheet (heck, make a new tab just for this and delete it after), you need pairs of "test - result" and have to put them in the right order just like when planning one like you did, so use column A to wrie the test and column B to write the result, and do all the test-result pairs you need. You can easily move them up and down amongst each other to get them in the right order so they work properly. Once you have that, in column C write a simple joining formula, or concatenate or concat or textjoin, whatever you like or your version of Excel has, that puts that row's columns A and B together with a comma between them. Then write a joining (and textjoining will work fantastically here, though concat-ing would be killer too) that puts all of that in a single long string. Start the joining with `"IFS(` and end it with `)` and you have your complete formula, or at least this portion of it. Copy, paste as a value, then F2 and copy the whole string. Go to the right cell (so the cell references you typed in the test-result pairs work) or any cell (planning to edit all those references after doing this) and paste it in. Yay.

The `IFS()` thing brings up one last thought here, unique to this formula, but something people do all the time and get hosed by:  every `IFS()` should end with either the last possibility in the world so ALL the possible outcomes are dealt with, OR it should end with a pair like this:  `TRUE,result` so that if everything you check out fails, the formula still has a result. It might be like what follows, it might say something else. But it points out that all of it failed and something you did not provide for is the case. You then figure out how important, or not important, that fact is.

In your formula's case, that happens. The last stuff you typed can still fail to fit and then you're out of wind. You have no more testing, and not even an error message to yourself. The best you'd hope for is the cell ends up with `FALSE` as a result. Imagine, for instance, if N11 has nothing at all in it. Or something like "horse" that doesn't match any of the things you look for. You don't deal with that, so it's a risk. Masybe you planned that, but if not, it's a risk to the integrity, the validity of your work.

Also, you can tighten up the way the tests are presented. Not a problem with a thousand rows, and that's all the work the spreadsheet does. But if you have 20,000 rows for Excel to work twice as hard in, and nine other columns all with formulas Excel has to compute, well... could bog up a bit. The following will do what you do, but is more carefully written to take advantage of some of the efficiencies your tests offer:

```
=IF(N11="MS",  IF(  M11<3.4,  "",  IF(M11>5.4,  0.8126*M11+1.1723,  0.5716*M11+2.498)    ),
 IF(N11="mb",  IF(  OR(M11<3.9,  M11>6.8),  "",  1.0319*M11+0.0223),
 IF(N11="ML",  IF(  OR(M11<3.3,  M11>6.6),  "",  0.8095*M11+1.3003),  "N11 = Something Else")))
```

In a tighter, more efficiently written formula, mistakes like that extra `)` are easier to spot if they happen and less likely to even happen. You see a pattern to it if you break the lines like I do here, and we humans focus right in on patterns! Let yourself help yourself here. You can always take the extra white space out and the `Alt-Enter`'s at the end if you wish. The jumble Excel offers on its own doesn't help anyone! Help YOU. Like in the play, "to thine own self be true"... pops meant 'you'd better care about yourself 'cause no one else ever will' and by 'no one else' he meant Excel. `Help YOU help YOURSELF.`

Comment: Its been really helpful. Thank you so much Jeorje.